# SQL (sqlite) java with table link, Where selection not working

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I am querying my database using this SQL query:

```
String findShift =("SELECT      
 SHIFTS.STARTTIME, SHIFTS.ENDTIME, SHIFTS.DATE, EMPLOYEES.FIRSTNAME, EMPLOYEES.SURNAME
 FROM SHIFTS
 INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES
 ON SHIFTS.STAFFID = EMPLOYEES.STAFFID
 WHERE SHIFTS.DATE = ('"+date+"');");
```

It working correctly without the where part but returns nothing with the where part. The query should return the start times, end times, first and surnames on a given date which is passed into the method as a parameter.
The tables being used are Employees and Shifts.

Comment: You should be using a parameterized select which will ensure the value within `date` is both *safe* and *correctly formatted* - which currently it probably isn't.

Comment: How would change it to a parameterized select ?

Comment: By [using `PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of concatenating strings and parameters together into an SQL statement.

Comment: I already assign my SQL query string to a prepared statement, before I perform the query.

Comment: The point is not the `PreparedStatement` class itself, but using parameters (`WHERE Shifts.Date = ?`).